# JQuery - Select asp object

Tags: jquery, asp.net

If it is possible to select an asp object like asp:Label by JQuery?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 main ways of selecting an element in jQuery.

By Id

```
$('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>');
```

By css Class

```
$('.className');
```

By attribute or tag type

```
$('input[name=lblName]');
```

Refer to this link for more ways of selecting an element
[How do i use jQuery selectors?](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_selectors.ashx)

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

A coworker of mine wrote a post on how to extend jQuery to do exactly what you're wanting.  The result is the ability select an asp control like this:

```
$(":asp(txtName)")
```

He accomplishes this by basically adding the following function:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].asp = function(elem, i, match) {
    return (elem.id && elem.id.match(match[3] + "$"));
}
```

For a full explanation, please see his post here: [Extending jQuery to Select ASP Controls](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/extending-jquery-to-select-asp-controls/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the example below:

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

You can access it with jquery with:

```
var label = $("[id$=_Label1]");
```

The id is the key.

Also the down-slash is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Well all the asp controls will be finally rendered as HTML controls by ASP.NET.

Like asp:textbox rendered as input type text. So you can use iQuery to select them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. If you have label with some id. For example 
you can select this label with

```
$('#Lbl1')
```

If you are using MasterPage you'll probably have to append some text infront of id..

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_Lbl1')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add class to the lable and access it

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="lblTest"></asp:Label>

$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.lblTest')///code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%= YourLabelID.ClientID %>")
```